# Prisma CreateMany Vs Transaction

Tags: node.js, prisma

I have a scenario when I wanted to create many records at a time and wanted to returns all created records. For that we can user any two of given approach.

1. Use prisma.users.createMany({ data: [{}, {}] }) and fetch record using prisma.users.findMany({}) and then return all records.
2. User prisma.$transaction([{}, {}]) and return all records.

So, which one is better approach ?. If there is any better another approach you have, you are always welcome.

I have tried both the ways but could not able to decide which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding any discussion about performance, I think each type of transaction is a tradeoff of convenience vs. flexibility. So I would approach it like this:

1. if you can use one of the high-level `doMany` functions, use that. Its clear the intent and the code is straightforward.
2. If you need to create multiple things at once and ensure rollback if any of them fail, but they are not all of the same type, then use `prisma.transaction([])`. you simply pass in all the calls you want without awaiting them.
3. If you need even more complex logic, possibly other checks in between step in the transaction or possibly throwing an error, use what prisma calls "interactive" transactions. This is the more traditional approach where all work is done inside of a callback:

```
await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
  // use tx instead of prisma
  await tx.users.create()
  await tx.emails.create()
```

I think which one is "best" is determined by which one you are able to use for your use-case, the more complex the problem you will have to use the option that supports it.

In terms of performance, its not clear from the docs if a batch op (e.g. createMany) is more performant. The docs only state that the batch is ran in a single transaction, not a single query (e.g. `COPY`)

Comment: To correct your last note re: performance - Prisma docs do state that:
`createMany uses a single INSERT INTO statement with multiple values` rather than a single transaction.

[Create multiple records - docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create-multiple-records)